# import yaml file with svelte

Tags: yaml, svelte

Svelte can natively import `json` file

how to make this possible with a `yaml` file?

```html
<script>
  import data from 'data.yml'
  console.log(data)
</script>
```

Comment: I'm porting from Vue with Webpack, which has `yaml-loader` and also having this issue. Svelte toots their own horn quite a bit, so far, the amount of friction in Svelte is about 10x that of React or Vue. Prettier code though.

There no world where you'll convince me that https://github.com/Modyfi/vite-plugin-yaml/tree/main/example is cleaner than `import member from 'file.yaml'`

Answer (score 0):

As I recently had this use case, let me share what I found.

Firstly, JSON and YAML resulting data structures (basically objects/maps and arrays/lists) are quite similar and you can easily switch from one to the other, i.e. in your case converting to JSON before loading into Svelte, e.g. using Python of Node in the backend.

To use directly an YAML file into Svelte, you can use the usual methods to upload it and then convert it to JS objects and arrays, like uploading JSON would do directly. To do that, I found js-yaml very effective and easy to use.

Answer (score -2):

Svelte does not do anything. It all depends on the bundler/build tools, which usually support things like JSON.

If you want to import YAML, you need a plugin/loader for whatever build system you are using, and if none exist, you can write your own.